# Cannot get the replacement of card

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck at this for very long. I dont know why my replacement for card table is 0 all the way.

Asked my friend's help and they tell me it is something to do with joining the card table.

QQn:For a given period (bounded by two given dates inclusive), say 01 December 2002 to 31 July 2003, find the set of the people who have at least one EZ link card issued within the specified period.

For EACH person in the set, list the

(i) Owner NRIC,

(ii) the total number of his/her cards issued during 
the period,

(iii) total number of card replacements (till current date) that have been made by the 
owner for only those cards that were issued during the given period.

List your results in ascending order of Owner NRIC.

For example, person S1111111 has 5 cards C1 (issued on 2 Jan 2001), C2 (issued on Dec 11 2002), C3 (issued on July 20 2003 as a replacement for C1), C4 (issued on July 21 
2003 as a replacement for C2), and C5 (issued on August 2 2012 as a replacement for C4).

I have solved part i and ii but cannot solve iii.

Here is my query:

```
create table card
(
CardID  int not null primary key,
OwnerNRIC   char(9),
IssuedDcardate  date,
StoredValue decimal (5,2),
OldCardID   int,
constraint card_fk foreign key (OldCardID) references card(CardID)
);


SELECT ownerNRIC AS NRIC,
  COUNT(ownerNRIC) AS Total_Cards_Issued_during_Period,
  COUNT(OldCardID) AS Total_Replacement_till_date_for_cards_issued_during_Period
FROM card

WHERE IssuedDcardate BETWEEN '2002-12-01' AND '2003-07-31' 
GROUP BY ownerNRIC;
```

Comment: What consitutes a replacement? If it's `OldCardID IS NOT NULL` then your query should work.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get this information is by using a subquery.  The subquery summarizes information by the old card id, and then joins it back in:

```
select ownerNRIC AS NRIC,
       COUNT(ownerNRIC) AS Total_Cards_Issued_during_Period,
       NumNewCards
from card c left outer join
     (select oldcardid, count(*) as numNewCards
      from card
      group by oldcardid
     ) oc
     on oc.oldcardId = c.cardid
WHERE IssuedDcardate BETWEEN '2002-12-01' AND '2003-07-31' 
group by ownerNRIC
```

Comment: Hi.Just to clarify.Why do i even need to have a join?Sorry,i am a beginner at this so my qns may sound stupid.